# Is it a good practice to separate socket server from API server?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sockets, redis

I'm building a full-stack web application. Backend is done in express, front-end in Vue.

The application has some real-time features, and for this I am using socket.io. Socket IO will have to keep track of some variables and react with different events to clients depending on current state of those variables. I intend to use redis to manage application state.

I would like to keep my API stateless, and separate my socket server from my API server (they would run on different ports). I would like to do this because I feel like it will be easier to manage, more scalable, and I think my security will benefit from this.

For authorized actions, client will send data to API, API will process the data and send it to the socket, and socket will emit changes to clients.
For unauthorized actions, I will use direct socket to client communication.

Is this a good way to structure my application?

Comment: Since I'm curious about this as well, and this was posted more than 2 years ago, I'm wondering if you've tried it by now and if so did you come to any conclusions?

Comment: Almost identical comment @Koy.  I had the same idea as the author - I've already built a bunch of traditional API responses, but I'd love to use a parallel socket server to handle a real-time feature on the website.  It's kind of surprising to me that nobody has weighed in on the 'best practice' part of it as well.  I'll keep looking elsewhere in the meantime.